# Can a template template be specialized for fundamental types like regular templates?

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming

I have written the following code to infix a templated class:

```
template<template<typename...> class C, typename A, typename B>
struct infix_t
{
    typedef C<A, B> type;
};

template<template<typename...> class C, class A>
constexpr infix_t<C, A> operator<(A, infix_t<C>)
{
    return {};
}


template<template<typename...> class C, typename A, typename B>
constexpr C<A, B> operator>(infix_t<C, A>, B)
{
    return {};
}
```

This allows me to write `a <same_as> b` where `same_as` has type `infix_t<std::is_same>`. However, if the type of `a` or `b` is a fundamental type, I get `template template argument has different template parameters...`; if I try to redeclare `infix_t` to accept fundamental types, I get `template argument ... must be a class template or alias template`. I thought that templates over typenames could accept fundamentals anyway. Is this because it's a template template, and the rules are different, or am I just approaching this wrong?

Comment: could you show example of calling code that gives this error?

Comment: What's the point of such weird syntax?

Comment: It actually doesn't require calling to give that error - the errors occur when I try to specialize the template. However, my intended use is `auto infixed = infix_t<other>` where `other` is a template over a typename and a fundamental, such as `std::integral_constant`.

Comment: Columbo, there is no real point; I read about this style in an article called "Syntactic Aspartame" (alluding to syntactic sugar.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand and modify the solution by @Yakk a bit, here's a version that allows compile-time comparison of types

```
#include <type_traits>

template<template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
struct infix {};

template<template<class...> class Op, class L>
constexpr infix<Op, L> operator<(L, infix<Op>)
{ return {}; }


template<template<class...> class Op, class L, class R>
constexpr Op<L, R> operator>(infix<Op, L>, R)
{ return {}; }

constexpr auto same_as  = infix<std::is_same>{};

template<int N>
constexpr auto int_c = std::integral_constant<int, N>::value;

int main()
{
    static_assert( int_c<0> <same_as> int_c<0> );
    static_assert( !(int{} <same_as> char{}) );
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01476ca1424674e4)

Answer (score 2):

To make your code compile, it is pretty easy:

```
template<template<class...> class C, class...Z>
struct infix_t {};

template<template<class...> class C, class A>
constexpr infix_t<C, A> operator<(A, infix_t<C>)
{ return {}; }


template<template<class...> class C, class A, class B>
constexpr C<A, B> operator>(infix_t<C, A>, B)
{ return {}; }
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/877d6c5e7fb1bdc5).

If you want to take `std::integral_constant` and apply this, you first wrap it up:

```
template<class T, class U>
using bob = std::integral_constant<T, U{}>;
```

now `bob` is an `integral_constant` that only takes types.  It expects the second type to encode the value of the constant, and the first the type.

This is turtles all the way down, in that `U` is probably itself going to be an integral constant.

There is no way to take the value `7` and generate an integral constant from an expression.  You can take the *token* `7_constant` and generate `std::integral_constant<int, 7>`, but that is a different problem.

Comment: hmm, I thought the OP wanted to be able to say `int <same_as> int` (or Boost.Hana style `0_c <same_as> 0_c`), not `0 <same_as> 0`. Can't see a way to do the former. Also, without the nested type, should probably just use `infix` instead of `infix_t`

Comment: @temp sure. They could `tag<int> <same_as> tag<int>` tho.